# how can i substring character from compilation of two string to be equal to max length 35

Tags: java, methods

I am facing an issue in writing the java method for the below scenario. I have two String one called (error code and error Description). I want to combine both and make sure that both are in length of 35 when they are combined. I am receiving the String from users so I am not sure about the size.
I wrote the below methods

```
private String error(Response response) {
    String errorCode = response.getErrorCode();
    String errorDescription = response.getErrorDescription();
    String info = errorCode +" "+errorDescription;
    return subtractInfo(info);
}

private String subtractInfo(String content) {
   String info = content.replaceAll("[-+^]*", "");
    return content.substring(0, Math.min(info.length(), 35));
}
```

The issue is I want to keep the value of the errorCode String as its, and start substring from the beginning of the errorDescription String. So the total should be 35 along with removing a special characters from both if exist. how can I handle the unknown length for both strings
example:

```
errorCode=ERR000

errorDescription=ACCOUNT : 01234567891 PASSED IN PART_TRAN_1 IS INVALID ACCT
```

output should be:

```
ERR000: PART_TRAN_1 IS INVALID ACCT
```

Comment: What if the errorCode is longer than 35 characters?

Comment: Also `and start substring from the beginning of the errorDescription String` doesnt match your input/output. With that input, the output should be `ERR000: ACCOUNT : 01234567891 PASSE`. Otherwise you need to clarify how the start is defined for the errorDescription

Answer (score 0):

If you keep all the errorCode you can use it's length to determine how more characters you need:

```
int n = 35 - errorCode.length();
```

And, in case errorDescription isn't long enough:

```
int i = (n<=errorDescription.length()) ? n : errorDescription.length();
```

Then,

```
String info = errorCode + errorDescription.substring(0,n);
```

Comment: That is exactly what `content.substring(0, Math.min(info.length(), 35))` is already doing. Keeps the whole code (as long as its shorter than 35 chars) and removes everything from the description which exceeds the threshold

Comment: My bad, I didn't saw this line.